# How is erasing MTD with "dd if=/dev/zero" different from "flash_eraseall"?

Tags: linux, flash-memory

`flash_eraseall <mtd device>` is specifically provided command to erase all of the MTD (device). What is the difference between it and `dd if=/dev/zero of=<mtd device>`?

Comment: Note, if using the **jffs2** filesystem, you should use `flash_eraseall -j` [as explained here](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/faq/jffs2.html#L_clmarker). (flash_eraseall erases flash naturally to byte value 0xff, not 0x00 like your `dd`.)

Comment: @meuh.   agree.  if you just "cat /dev/mtdblockxxx" you can always see the tail end of the partition filled with 0xff.   And this writing with 0xff is required by the hardware specs in the MTD datasheet as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both SDDs and MTDs have a lifespan and are rate to a certain number of writes. Early MTDs were rated for 1000s of erase/write cycles. Many MTDs are not actually block devices, but the Linux driver emulates it as such, and presents a block layer. Or the standard block size (512) might be much larger on the underlying hardware. If you write consecutive 512-byte blocks, but the underlying technology is 4K chunks, you will cause the underlying layer's block to be written 8 times. In some MTDs, you're rewriting the entire flash cell every write.

> [the `mtdblock` driver] works by caching a whole flash erase block in RAM, modifying it as requested, then erasing the whole block and writing back the modified. This means that mtdblock does not try to do any optimizations, and that you will lose lots of data in case of power cuts. And last, but not least, mtdblock does not do any wear-leveling or bit-flips handling. [1](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/doc/general.html#L_mtdblock)

Almost ALL MTD devices support a total-erase operation. In addition to the benefits of being reliable and complete erasure more-or-less guaranteed, it is easier and better for the device.

There are certain devices you should not zero-out with `dd if=/dev/zero`:

- SDD (Solid-state disks)
- MTD (Memory technology devices)
- COW and other thin-provisioned virtual disks

MTD for the reasons above. For COW (copy-on-write) filesystems/disks, you will end up forcing the underlying block driver to allocate blocks that were previously not in existence, and you will not be overwriting old/existing data.  SDDs also employ certain wear-leveling algorithms similar to COW, where previously unwritten blocks will be written to, rather than overwriting existing ones (so, for data-security, zeroing out the device in this was is ill-advised). Many STA and SAS devices offer block-level encryption using a master key, which the BIOS remembers and communicates to it on boot. You can effectively erase the block device simply by erasing or resetting the master key.

Comment: Would it be fare to say that for MTD, the only difference is that `dd` wears the device significantly more?